# Open edit-server files from emacsclient in a specific frame

Tags: frames, emacsclient

Is there a way to designate a specific frame in which files opened with `emacsclient` will appear?

I have one monitor that is dedicated to a fullscreen Emacs frame.  I do most of my editing in that monitor, but from time to time I will open a second frame on another monitor temporarily.  I want to ensure that every time I open a file using `emacsclient`, it gets sent to my fullscreen frame and doesn't end up on any other frames that might be open.

**Edit:**

The ideal workflow would be that my **initial** emacs frame gets tagged as the recipient of all `emacsclient` requests, and the rest is automatic.  I always use the initial frame as my primary emacs frame, and other frames come and go as needed.

Comment: Which operating system are you running?  Answers may vary if your window system is X, Windows, Mac OS.

Comment: @purple_arrows Typically I am on Linux, but I also use Emacs on Mac and Windows.  Also, I would like to be able to send the file to a specific **frame** if possible, not just a specific display.

Comment: It'll take me a while to get back to an answer that (fingers crossed) works cross platforms.  `server-select-display` does the work of selecting the frame to use, and unfortunately it doesn't offer any hooks to customize.

Answer (score 2):

If your windowing system is X and your monitors are configured as separate screens, you can pass the appropriate `DISPLAY` value (e.g. `:0.0` or `:0.1`) to emacsclient with the `-d` option.  That's kind of a big "if".

Comment: I am using X, and `-d :0.0` works fine, but for some reason `-d :0.1` gives an error: `Display :0.1 can't be opened`.

Comment: Your monitors may be set up as one big screen, as opposed to two separate screens.  You can tell if you can drag an (X) window a/k/a (Emacs) frame from one monitor to the other - if that's the case, then this solution won't work for you.

Comment: You are right. This won't work for me, because my monitors are configured as a single display.

Answer (score 2):

I have *some* success with the following command:

```
emacsclient --eval "(select-frame (car (frames-on-display-list)))"; sleep 1s; emacsclient -n file.txt
```

The lisp code selects the first frame. To select the second one you should replace car with cadr. But I have not found a way to know which frame is the first ;)

Bests,

Jacek

Comment: The sleep shouldn't be neccesary, because emacsclient only returns when eval is done.